Adding API route to the server of an Angular SSR project is not working as I expected
for an API, I'm trying to add a path for the Node Express server from an Angular SSR project.
After some trouble, I thought I should reduce the problem. So, I used a Postman request to talk directly to the server.
This is my /server.ts:
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { CommonEngine } from '@angular/ssr';
import express from 'express';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';
import { dirname, join, resolve } from 'node:path';
import bootstrap from './src/main.server';


// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const serverDistFolder = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
  const browserDistFolder = resolve(serverDistFolder, '../browser');
  const indexHtml = join(serverDistFolder, 'index.server.html');

  const commonEngine = new CommonEngine();

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', browserDistFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('**', express.static(browserDistFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y',
    index: 'index.html',
  }));

  server.get('/api/test', function(req, res){
    console.log("test first")
    res.json({test:"test"})
  })


  // All regular routes use the Angular engine
  server.get('**', (req, res, next) => {
    const { protocol, originalUrl, baseUrl, headers } = req;

    commonEngine
      .render({
        bootstrap,
        documentFilePath: indexHtml,
        url: `${protocol}://${headers.host}${originalUrl}`,
        publicPath: browserDistFolder,
        providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: baseUrl }],
      })
      .then((html) => res.send(html))
      .catch((err) => next(err));
  });


  return server;
}


function run(): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

run();


I think the only change I have made is adding the following:
server.get('/api/test', function(req, res){
    console.log("test first")
    res.json({test:"test"})
  })

This is my error, when I call http://localost:4200/api/test via postman
ERROR RuntimeError: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'api/test'
    at Recognizer.noMatchError (angular-client/.angular/cache/18.2.10/angular-client/vite/deps_ssr/@angular_router.js:2732:12)
    at eval (angular-client/.angular/cache/18.2.10/angular-client/vite/deps_ssr/@angular_router.js:2764:20)
    at eval (angular-client/.angular/cache/18.2.10/angular-client/vite/deps_ssr/chunk-77RZBIYQ.js:5844:49)
    at OperatorSubscriber2.OperatorSubscriber2._this._error (angular-client/.angular/cache/18.2.10/angular-client/vite/deps_ssr/chunk-77RZBIYQ.js:909:13)
    at OperatorSubscriber2.Subscriber2.error (angular-client/.angular/cache/18.2.10/angular-client/vite/deps_ssr/chunk-77RZBIYQ.js:520:16)
    at OperatorSubscriber2.Subscriber2._error (angular-client/.angular/cache/18.2.10/angular-client/vite/deps_ssr/chunk-77RZBIYQ.js:543:28)
    at OperatorSubscriber2.Subscriber2.error (angular-client/.angular/cache/18.2.10/angular-client/vite/deps_ssr/chunk-77RZBIYQ.js:520:16)
    at OperatorSubscriber2.Subscriber2._error (angular-client/.angular/cache/18.2.10/angular-client/vite/deps_ssr/chunk-77RZBIYQ.js:543:28)
    at OperatorSubscriber2.Subscriber2.error (angular-client/.angular/cache/18.2.10/angular-client/vite/deps_ssr/chunk-77RZBIYQ.js:520:16)
    at OperatorSubscriber2.Subscriber2._error (angular-client/.angular/cache/18.2.10/angular-client/vite/deps_ssr/chunk-77RZBIYQ.js:543:28) {
  code: 4002
}


I had to add a proxy bypass to reach the server in a SSR project.
To do so, add that to your angular.json
  "projects": {
    "project": {
      "architect": {
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
          },


in you configuration src/proxy.conf.json, you can define routs to bypass the the ng server build
{
   "/auth": {
     "target": "http://localhost:4000",
     "secure": false
   }
}


In your package.json you should have a script
"serve:ssr:project": "node dist/project/server/server.mjs"

Then you have to start the server via npm run serve:ssr:project next to you ng serve. You can also omit ng serve when you are only work on the server.

You should always place your API routes above the wild card route (**), that might be the reason the API is not reached. Since from top to bottom is the priority, the top wildcard route, captures the route before the actual route.
  server.get('/api/test', function(req, res){
    console.log("test first")
    res.json({test:"test"})
  })
  server.get('**', express.static(browserDistFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y',
    index: 'index.html',
  }));


Currently (as of v19) Angular CLI generates this kind of server.ts file with explicit place for API routes in it (commented):
import {
  AngularNodeAppEngine,
  createNodeRequestHandler,
  isMainModule,
  writeResponseToNodeResponse,
} from '@angular/ssr/node';
import express from 'express';
import { dirname, resolve } from 'node:path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';

const serverDistFolder = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
const browserDistFolder = resolve(serverDistFolder, '../browser');

const app = express();
const angularApp = new AngularNodeAppEngine();

/**
 * Example Express Rest API endpoints can be defined here.
 * Uncomment and define endpoints as necessary.
 *
 * Example:
 * ```ts
 * app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => {
 *   // Handle API request
 * });
 * ```
 */

/**
 * Serve static files from /browser
 */
app.use(
  express.static(browserDistFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y',
    index: false,
    redirect: false,
  }),
);

/**
 * Handle all other requests by rendering the Angular application.
 */
app.use('/**', (req, res, next) => {
  angularApp
    .handle(req)
    .then((response) =>
      response ? writeResponseToNodeResponse(response, res) : next(),
    )
    .catch(next);
});

/**
 * Start the server if this module is the main entry point.
 * The server listens on the port defined by the `PORT` environment variable, or defaults to 4000.
 */
if (isMainModule(import.meta.url)) {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

/**
 * The request handler used by the Angular CLI (dev-server and during build).
 */
export const reqHandler = createNodeRequestHandler(app);


